# sheaves exactness

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

We have an exact sequence of sheaves:

0 $\to$ F' $\to$ F $\to$ F'' $\to$ 0

Then we have exactness of 0 $\to$ F'|U $\to$ F|U $\to$ F''|U $\to$ 0 for an open U of X as exactness of sheaves is stalkwise.

I don't quite follow the last statement from P382 of Rotman's Intro to Homological Algebra because he states on P301 that an exact sequence in **pSh** implies the its exactness in **Sh**, but the converse is not true.

In other words, I don't quite see how being exact on stalks implies the exact sequence: 0 $\to$ F'|U $\to$ F|U $\to$ F''|U $\to$ 0. The converse is true, I am aware.

Any enlightenment would be appreciated!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does "F|U" mean $\mathcal{F}|_U$, the restriction of the sheaf $\mathcal F$ to the open set $U$?

Comment: yes, you're right! This is how Rotman wrote it, not in the subscript form. Thx!

Comment: A sequence of presheaves is exact iff exact on sections; a sequence of sheaves is exact iff exact on stalks.

Comment: You should learn how to use mathjax to make your post more readable: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference